# jQuery UI autocomplete with custom data from Facebook Graph API friends

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

i want my facebook graph api /me/friends list in an autocomplete field. I want choose my friend, select one of them end have its ID.

Facebook response with a "data" json object with name and id. Perfect!
Some code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    FB.api('/me/friends', function(fbresponse){

        $("#input_13").autocomplete({
                source : function(request, response){
                    response($.map(fbresponse.data, function(e){
                        return{
                            id : e.id, 
                            name : e.name
                        }
                    }))
                },
                select : function(event, ui){
                            alert(ui.item.name);
                            $("#input_13").val(ui.item.name);
                            $("#input_10").val(ui.item.id);
                            return false;
                }
            }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
                    return $("<li></li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                            .append( $("<a></a>").html(item.name) )
                            .appendTo(ul); 
                        };

    });


});
```

Results is at 90%, when I begin typing, the list of my friends appears but it's order from the first to the end, it's not filtered.
Example: 
My list complete is:
marco
massimo
marino
mimmo
simone
sara
sonia

when I begin with "s" should result only
simone
sara
sonia

but the result list does not change.

What's happen? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As your source property is pointing to a function it is called ever the plugin needs the datasource, the problem is: the FB Graph API don't accept a "term" param when searching for friends so it returns always the same data based on your input. What you need is something like this:

```
var makeItems = function(fbresponse) {
  return $.map(fbresponse, function(item) {
    return {
      label: item.name,
      value: item.id,
    }
  });
};

var setAutoComplete = function(parsed_items) {
  $("#input_13").autocomplete({
    source : parsed_items,
    select : function(event, ui){
      alert(ui.item.name);
      $("#input_13").val(ui.item.name);
      $("#input_10").val(ui.item.id);
      return false;
    }
  }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append( $("<a></a>").html(item.name) )
      .appendTo(ul); 
  };
};

FB.api('/me/friends', function(fbresponse) {
  setAutoComplete(makeItems(fbresponse.data));
});
```

It will make only one request, will get all the friends and set a variable with an array of parsed items so the filter can act in the array.

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this code example, its working fine.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alon_nativ/archive/2011/05/30/search-facebook-friends-with-jquery-autocomplete.aspx